# Convert an .xlsb file to .xlsx

Tags: python, r

Suppose I have `file.xlsb`.  I would like to convert it to `file.xlsx` programmatically using R.  How can I do this?

I have tried using both `openxlsx::read.xlsx()` and `readxl::read_excel()` to read the files (to then later write to `.xlsx`),  but both are unable to read this file extension.  The error message in `readxl::read_excel()` is a little cryptic, but I assume it's because of the `.xlsb` file extension.

```r
openxlsx::read.xlsx('file.xlsb')
#> Error: openxlsx can only read .xlsx or .xlsm files

readxl::read_excel('file.xlsb')
#> Error: expected <
```

I've seen a way to do it [using python](https://pypi.org/project/xlsb2xlsx/), which I imagine can be used with `reticulate`, but I am not familiar enough with python to know how to use that.

Comment: There's a library just for that https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxlsb/vignettes/read-xlsb-workbook.html

Comment: @smartse, that package has one function, `read_xlsb()`, that is meant to "import a region from a binary format Excel workbook (xlsb)."  My goal isn't to read the data into R, but rather to change the file format of an existing file.

Comment: Yes but if you read it in then you can write it back out with openxlsx. There's no way that you're going to find a function which just converts between the two out of the box.

Comment: @smartse, such a function exists in python:  https://pypi.org/project/xlsb2xlsx/.  I just don't know how to use it...

Answer (score 1):

in python you can convert the xlbs file to pandas and save it as xlsx

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file_path.xlsb', engine = 'pyxlsb')
df.to_excel('file_name.xlsx')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: I tried this, and it mangled the file.  It only outputs one sheet with everything crammed into it.

Comment: mm maybe if you specify the sheets

Answer (score 1):

In `openxlsx2` release 1.1 a basic `xlsb` parser was [introduced](https://janmarvin.github.io/openxlsx2/news/index.html#openxlsx2-11). But be aware that it has limits and not all features of the office open xml spreadsheet file format are supported. Your best choice is still to open the file in Excel to convert it manually.

```
openxlsx2::wb_load("file.xlsb")$open()
```